# Different colour for new tabs in iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm

Is there any way to change tab colour for new tabs in iTerm2 (automatically, random colour)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new python script in the scripts folder, name it new_colored_tab.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import iterm2
import random

def rand_color():
    return random.randint(0,255)

async def main(connection):
    app=await iterm2.async_get_app(connection)
    session=app.current_terminal_window.current_tab.current_session
    window = app.current_window
    if window is not None:
        await window.async_create_tab()
    else:
        print("No current window")

    change = iterm2.LocalWriteOnlyProfile()
    color = iterm2.Color(rand_color(),rand_color(),rand_color())

    change.set_tab_color(color)
    change.set_use_tab_color(True)
    await session.async_set_profile_properties(change)

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Every time you want a new tab, go to the Scripts menu and run it.

Answer (score 4):

With iTerm open, go to the iterm2 menu item and select preferences. From preferences, you'll get a panel that looks like the image below.

[image]

From this image select the Profiles icon in the top row. This shows the following panel.

[image]

From this panel click on colors that brings up this final panel.

[image]

you can see in this panel there is a checkbox labeled tab color. This allows you to set your tab color. All tabs opened now will use this new color.

Comment: thank you, but I would like to set random color for newly opened tabs.

Comment: You could write an AppleScript to do this and then use App Shortcuts to assign it a keyboard shortcut (maybe): https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html

Comment: AppleScript is deprecated now use Python-Api like the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

to support random color automaticly when using `color` without argument

add the following lines to `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
PRELINE="\r\033[A"

function random {
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
}

function color {
    case $1 in
    green)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;57\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;197\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;77\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    red)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;270\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;60\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;83\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    orange)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;227\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;143\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;10\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    *)
    random
    esac
}

#color    #uncomment to enable automatically set random color when tab created
```

After each time a new iterm2 tab created, use command `color` to automaticly give it a new/random color.

if you want the iterm2-tab color set automatically whenever it is created, then .just add `color` to then end of `.zshrc` / `.profile` or just after the `function color`

Comment: This is helpful, i customize it further with my project_folder color. Anytime i am in project_folder, it turn violet. Thanks.